# angle bisector and concurrency problem.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7kIT.png)

In this figure, line BE is angle bisector of ∠ABC and some point X is on BE.
If ∠AEB=∠FDB, then prove ∠EDF is right angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to guess what the correct statement of the problem should be.

> **Problem**:  Let the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$ meet $AC$ at $E$, and let $X$ be a point on $BE$.  Extend $AX,CX$ to intersect $BC,AB$ at $D,F$ respectively.  If $\angle AEB=\angle FDB$, prove that $\angle EDF$ is a right angle.

Extend $EA$ and $DF$ to meet at $Y$.  Then $\angle YEB=\angle AEB=\angle FDB=\angle YDB$, so $Y,E,D,B$ concyclic.  We now have everything in the diagram (except the point $O$, which is a distraction).

By Ceva's theorem, we have
$$
\frac{AF}{FB}\frac{BD}{DC}\frac{CE}{EA}=1
$$
since $AD,BE,CF$ are concurrent.  On the other hand, by Menelau's theorem, since $Y,F,D$ are collinear,
$$
\frac{AF}{FB}\frac{BD}{DC}\frac{CY}{YA}=-1.
$$
So
$$
\frac{CY}{YA}=-\frac{CE}{EA}.
$$
But $BE$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$!  The angle bisector theorem gives
$$
\frac{CE}{EA}=\frac{BC}{BA}
$$
i.e., $Y$ divides $CA$ externally in the ratio
$$
CY:YA=BC:BA
$$
so $BY$ is the external angle bisector of $\triangle ABC$ at $B$ (the [external angle bisector theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1363161)).
Thus $\angle EDF=\angle EDY=\angle EBY$ is a right angle (internal and external angle bisectors of $\angle B$ are orthogonal).

Comment: Thank you, sir.
It's very helpful to me.
I'm not good at edit and posting words.
Your presentation is beautiful